# Proof of converse of Pythagoras theorem

Tags: geometry, triangles, alternative-proof, pythagorean-triples

It is well known that the Pythagoras theorem has numerous proofs. But I not able to prove the converse of Pythagoras theorem without using the theorem itself. Is there a way to prove the converse without using the theorem? If yes, please help me to do it.

Comment: Would you please state the theorem and tell us precisely what you're struggling to prove?

Comment: It follows from the law of cosines, which can be proved without using Pythagoras' theorem.

Comment: I just want to clarify that using the Pythagorean theorem to prove the inverse of the Pythagorean theorem is not circular reasoning. You have already proved it, you are free to use it from now on...

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I proved it using heron's formula for area of triangle

Comment: Thanks everyone for your help. I proved it using heron's formula for area of triangle